# Getter and assertsEquals function

Tags: java, junit

I have written a code for `Person` class and in that class create a constructor `Person` and argument `name`. Now I have to create an instance of this class will offer a getter for the person's name and also create an instance of this class will respond to a `greet` method that accepts one argument: message.

When the message is *"Hello"*, greet must return:

> Hi, I'm {{name}}

When the message is *"Goodbye"*, greet must return:

> Bye

When the message is anything else, `greet` will return the message that it was provided. I have a tested case code but I am stuck with `assertEquals()` function and getter function. Now I am facing error with `assertfunction`. Can anybody please tell me how does `assertfucntion` and getter works? I have implemented getter in my code, I'm but not sure whether I did it right.

Here's my code:

```
class Person
{
    private String name;

    Person(String n)
    {
        n = name;
    }

    String GetName()
    {
        return this.name; 
    }

    public void greet(String t)
    {    
        if (t == "Hello")
        {
            System.out.println("Hi my name is "+name);
        }
        else if (t == "Goodbye")
        {
            System.out.println("bye");
        }
        else
            System.out.println("Hi, my name is"+name);
    }
}
```

Test code:

```
import static org.junit.Assert.*;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.Before;

public class TestPerson {
    private Person jeff;
    private Person susy;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        jeff = new Person("Jeff");
        susy = new Person("Susy");
    }

    @Test
    public void testGetName() {
        assertEquals("Jeff", jeff.GetName());
    }

    @Test
    public void testGreetHelloJeff() {
        assertEquals("Hi, I'm Jeff", jeff.greet("Hello"));
    }

    @Test
    public void testGreetHelloSusy() {
        assertEquals("Hi, I'm Susy", susy.greet("Hello"));
    }

    @Test
    public void testGreetGoodbye() {
        assertEquals("Bye", jeff.greet("Goodbye"));
    }

    @Test
    public void testGreetOther() {
        assertEquals("Yo", jeff.greet("Yo"));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You cannot compare a `String` and the return value of a method that returns `void`.

Your Person class is odd.  You have it too closely tied to System.out, which is not useful.

Your code has a lot of problems for such a small sample size.  Here's what I might suggest:

```
public class Person {

    private String name;

    Person(String n) {
        this.name = n;
    }

    String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    public String greet(String t) {
        if ("Hello".equals(t)) {
            return String.format("Hi my name is %s", name);
        } else if ("Goodbye".equals(t)) {
            return "bye";
        } else {
            return String.format("Hi, my name is %s", name);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: if "Hello" and `else` should do the same, wouldn't it be better to just check for "Goodbye" and do the rest in `else`? This also prevents differences, like typos, in both versions.

Comment: Agree, I thought of that after I posted the code.  The class is trivial enough where I didn't care, but real code should always strive to be as DRY as possible.

Answer (score 1):

See your method returns void:

```
 public void greet(String t)
```

How do you expect to get and assert a values of void?

Change void to String and do return a message string.
Also do not use == rather .equals(..)

"Hello" case seems does the same as default. Better do:

```
public class Person {

    private String name;

    Person(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    public String greet(String m) {
        if ("Goodbye".equals(m)) {
            return "bye";
        } else {
            return String.format("Hi, my name is %s", name);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

By calling `assertEquals("Bye", jeff.greet("Goodbye"));` you're comparing the String "Bye" to `void` since `.greet` returns `void`.

Change greet to this:

```
public String greet(String t){    
     if(t.equals("Hello"))
         return "Hi my name is " + name;
     else if(t.equals("Goodbye"))
         return "bye";
     else
        return "Hi, my name is" + name;
 }
```

And then you can use the `assertEquals(String, String)` like:

```
assertEquals("bye", jeff.greet("Goodbye"));
```

In Java when comparing Strings use .equals() instead of ==.  So 'if(t=="Hello")"' would be 'if(t.equals("Hello"))'

Method names should start with a lower case letter.

Also String comparison is case sensitive so make sure you are using the correct case when comparing your Strings.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't make sense to test the `greet(String)` method using `assertEquals`, since the method doesn't return anything. The `assertEquals` is used to assert whether the actual result returned from a tested method is equal to an expected value that you provide, just like the `testGetName` above.

It seems more appropriate to change `void greet(String)` to `String greet(String)` which returns a greeting message according to the `t` argument to make your code more testable.

Moreover, you should use `aStr.equals(bStr)` instead of `aStr == bStr` to compare two String. `==` just compare the reference of the two String object rather than their values.